# Game theory - Pure ESS test

Tags: game-theory

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ describe a symmetric game with $n$ strategies.

For the sake of clarity, I call symmetric game a two-player game where payoff matrices are the same for both players.

Suppose that $x^* = e_i$ is a non-strict pure Nash equilibria ($e_i$ is the $i$-th versor of the space $\mathbb{R}^n$).

In order to prove that $x^*$ is $ESS$ I have to check that:

$${x^*}^T A y > y^T A y ~\forall y \neq x^*$$

where $y$ is a generic strategy such that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n y_k = 1 \wedge y_k \geq 0 ~\forall k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$$

I suppose the following fact: since $x^*$ is pure, then I have to check only that

$${x^*}^T A e_j > e_j^T A e_j ~\forall e_j \neq x^*$$

in order to say that $x^*$ is $ESS$.

Is this true? Is there some proof for this or for the contrary?

Comment: It seems that if a mixed strategy $y$ is better than $x*,$, at least one pure strategy $e_k$ must give a higher payoff than $x*$, by the linearity of the payoff matrix.  Is that enough?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm now a bit confused on notation: it seems that if $x*=e_i$ then you have only defined one player's strategy. Or are you just assuming we then check the conditions for each player?

Comment: The game is between two player. The notation $v^T A w$ indicates the payoff of a player that use the strategy $v$ while the opponent use the strategy $w$. Is this clearer now?

Comment: My confusion is that the Nash equilibria should specificy two vectors, denoting the pure strategy of each player, but $x*=e_i$ only seems to specify one. (even in a symmmetric game they may be different) Or maybe I'm confused about 'versor.'

Comment: For symmetric game I mean that payoff matrices are the same for both players and in general $A \neq A^T$. Then, a Nash equilibrium correspond to only one vector.

Comment: A **symmetric** Nash equilibrium correspond to only one vector. There are symmetric games (say with continuous action spaces and discontinuous payoffs) that have only asymmetric Nash equilibria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality, 
$${x^*}^T A y > y^T A y ~\forall y \neq x^*$$ is not linear in $y$ so the answer to the question is **no**.

Counter-example:

$$ \pmatrix{& A & B & C \\ A & 5,5 & 0,0 & 0,0\\B& 0,0& -1,-1& 90,90\\C& 0,0 & 90,90 & -1,-1}$$

Notice that:

1. (A,A) is a strict Nash equilibrium.
2. $u_1(A,B)=u_1(A,C)=0>u_1(B,B)=u_1(C,C)=-1$
3. (A,A) is not ESS (in mixed strategies) let $Z=\frac 12 B+ \frac 12 C$ then $u_1(A,Z)=0<u_1(Z,Z)=-\frac 12 + 45$.